# AngularJs Loop Clear

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm updating someones code but I have no idea where to start, my JavaScript skills are not bad but I've never used angular and cant get my head round the documentation.

Can anyone point me in the correct play to add a break every 3rd item on this code?

```
    <div class="product-holder" ng-class="{'no-margin': ($index%3 == 2)}" ng-repeat="product in products" my-post-repeat-directive>

        <h3><a ng-href="#event.buildLink( 'product' )#/{{slug(product)}}">{{product.TITLE}}</a></h3>
        <a ng-href="#event.buildLink( 'product' )#/{{slug(product)}}"><img class="product-image" src="assets/images/core/product-details/loading.gif" ng-src="userfiles/shop/products/thumbnails/{{product.THUMBNAIL}}" alt="{{product.TITLE}}"></a>
        <div class="details">
            <a class="btn btn-orange btn-view" ng-href="#event.buildLink( 'product' )#/{{slug(product)}}">View Details</a>
            <p ng-class="{'details-no-stock': !isInStock(product)}">{{product | pricetext}}<br>
                <span ng-show="isInStock(product)">In stock</span>
                <span ng-hide="isInStock(product)">Out of stock</span>
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>

    *I want to add a clear div here every 3 items in loop.
</div>
```

Many Thanks,
Brent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The $index in the main div is almost doing what you need.

```
ng-class="{'no-margin': ($index%3 == 2)}"
```

You can add a DIV using a similar approach (defining clear-div as needed):

```
<div ng-class="{'clear-div': ($index%3 == 0)}" />
```

[edit to tidy up the grammar a bit!]

Answer (score 0):

you would be better off using a css clear implementation based on that class being added but you could use an ng-if using the same logic at the ng-class in the first element based on the $index of the ng-repeat

here is an example of what that would look like in the html

```
 <div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <div ng-repeat="item in data">
        <div>{{$index}}. {{item.label}}</div>
        <div ng-if="$index % 3 == 2 ">------</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and an example fiddle of it in action http://jsfiddle.net/3wjKM/

note this will work in recent versions of angular but not earlier versions...

Comment: I have tried CSS logic but I cant use nth-child as it needs to work in ie8 +

Comment: @BrentFrench you are still supporting IE8? That sucks. Also break you lines if they get longer than 80 characters. line with product-image is certainly too long. This might seem like useless bullshit, but it really helps with merges down the line.